# How to add Header and Footer to each rendered page on pdf document using htmltopdf nativescript plugin

Tags: nativescript, html-to-pdf

I'm using the html2pdf Native script plugin, and would like to define a header and a footer to apply to each page. What is the most expedient method I can use to specify headers/footers with html2pdf in each page rendered on pdf documnet?

Comment: You will have to append your HTML content for header and footer to every page, there is no easy way around it.

Comment: why not make a StackLayout or GridLayout and make a Header / Content / Footer and put the HTMLView in the Content and have the header and footer populate based on a service or other method.

Comment: i tried both the ways above. as Manoj said it is not an easy way. can anyone give some idea on how to build html in such a way that each page contains header and footer. it it works then ill pass that html string to webview and generate pdf.